# Excel VBA - replace non-english characters

Tags: excel, vba, replace, character

im currently mapping some addresses from one excel sheet into another, this requires me to do specific things such as changing the column orders, deleting duplicate rows, and cutting the page into 100-row sheets...i also need to replace non-standard characters with their closest English equivalent.

I have a bit of code to accomplish this, and it works fine but its really slow, it looks like this:

```
Sub ReplaceCharacters()
'Replaces special characters for English
Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
        With rCell
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Á", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Å", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "á", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "å", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ð", "D")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ð", "D")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "É", "E")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "é", "e")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "í", "i")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Í", "I")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ó", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ó", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ú", "u")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ý", "Y")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ý", "y")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Þ", "Th")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "þ", "th")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Æ", "AE")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "æ", "ae")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ø", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ø", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ö", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ä", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ä", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ü", "U")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "À", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "à", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "È", "E")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "è", "e")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ì", "I")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ì", "i")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ò", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ò", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ù", "U")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ù", "u")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ç", "c")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ç", "C")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Â", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "â", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ê", "E")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ê", "e")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Î", "I")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "î", "i")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ô", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ô", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Û", "U")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "û", "u")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ñ", "N")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ñ", "n")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Õ", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "õ", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ã", "A")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ã", "a")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "É", "E")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "é", "e")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ë", "E")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ë", "e")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Í", "I")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "í", "i")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ï", "I")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ï", "i")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ö", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ö", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Õ", "O")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "õ", "o")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ú", "U")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ú", "u")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ü", "U")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ü", "u")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "Ÿ", "Y")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ÿ", "y")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "ß", "ss")
            .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(.Value, "œ", "oe")
        End With
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

I was wondering if there is a quicker way to accomplish the same end result of swapping non-standard characters with their english equivalents?

Also, i cant seem to get my head around how to ask the code to just sample all active rows, hence im needing to overestimate the number of rows:
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells

Any ideas how to just get it to change all active rows on the sheet?

Many thanks, im all very new to this :D

Answer (score 2):

This will be quite faster:

```
Sub ReplaceCharacters()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
      .Replace What:="Á", Replacement:="A", LookAt:=xlPart
      .Replace What:="Å", Replacement:="A", LookAt:=xlPart
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The screen updating is turned off, which saves all the flickering. Furthermore, the code does not loop through all the cells, but changes the range as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should see a dramatic reduction in processing time if you do the repetitive *replace* operations on an internal variable, then assign the final value to the cell.

```
Function EnglishChars(Text As Variant) As String
    Dim Charmap, s As String, i As Integer
    Charmap = Array("Á", "A", "Å", "A", "á", "a", "å", "a", "ð", "D", "Ð", "D", "É", "E", "é", "e", "í", "i", "Í", "I", "Ó", "O", "ó", "o", "ú", "u", "Ý", "Y", "ý", "y", "Þ", "Th", "þ", "th", "Æ", "AE", "æ", "ae", "Ø", "O", "ø", "o", "Ö", "O", "Ä", "A", "ä", "a", "Ü", "U", "À", "A", "à", "a", "È", "E", "è", "e", "Ì", "I", "ì", "i", "Ò", "O", "ò", "o", "Ù", "U", "ù", "u", "ç", "c", "Ç", "C", "Â", "A", "â", "a", "Ê", "E", "ê", "e", "Î", "I", "î", "i", "Ô", "O", "ô", "o", "Û", "U", "û", "u", "Ñ", "N", "ñ", "n", "Õ", "O", "õ", "o", "Ã", "A", "ã", "a", "É", "E", "é", "e", "Ë", "E", "ë", "e", "Í", "I", "í", "i", "Ï", "I", "ï", "i", "Ö", "O", "ö", "o", "Õ", "O", "õ", "o", "Ú", "U", "ú", "u", "Ü", "U", "ü", "u", "Ÿ", "Y", "ÿ", "y", "ß", "ss", "œ", "oe")
    s = Text
    For i = LBound(Charmap) To UBound(Charmap) Step 2
        s = Replace(s, Charmap(i), Charmap(i + 1))
    Next
    EnglishChars = s
End Function

Sub ReplaceCharacters()
'Replaces special characters for English
Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
        rCell.Value = EnglishChars(rCell.Value)
    Next rCell
End Sub
```