# Replace Numbers followed by Non-Printable Characters Chr(25) into Numbers followed by double quotation

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need to replace non-printable characters with double quotation " 
**The problem** is, this bad character `Chr(25)` can come after number, single time or twice and even comes after number and double quotation " 
If I used excel **clean function** ,that will remove all Chr(25) and not replace it.

```
Range("C2") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Range("B2"))
```

I also tried to use vba **Replace function**, but again the problem is count and position of Non-Printable Characters:

```
Range("C2") = Replace(Range("B2"), Chr(25) & Chr(25), """")
```

'If Chr(25) is single, this code will replace and add again

In advance, grateful for all your help.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50387976/4961700

Comment: I'd start by replacing all double instances of Chr(25) with a single instance - then you have a smaller number of cases to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a regular expression to catch and replace these characters:

```
Function RegexReplace(s As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "(\d+)[""']*\u0019+"
    .Global = True
    RegexReplace = .Replace(s, "$1""")
End With
    
End Function
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Trgmjr/1) of the pattern which means:

- `(\d+)` - Capture any 1+ digits in a capture group;
- `["']*` - Match 0+ double/single quotes;
- `\u0019+` - Match 1+ 'END OF MEDIUM' characters.

Replace with `$1"`  means to input the captured digits followed by a double quote.

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=RegexReplace(A1)
```

---

**Note:** If you don't need to specify the digits, you could leave `(\d+)` out and just use `["']*\u0019+` with a simple replacement of a single `"`.

Comment: It does not work with the third example `The 4''x6''` ,the output is the same string with non-Printable Characters

Comment: @Waleed, see my printscreen. It worked for me. Unless you don't really have double quotes but two single quotes? If you can confirm that you are using single quotes, then just edit the pattern to [`(\d+)[""']*\u0019+`](https://regex101.com/r/Trgmjr/1)

Comment: You are correct ,my apologies. Kindly could you update your answer accordingly.